# How to point to the last letter in the string?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to build a program that can find the order of a certain character in a string 
this is the code i made :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string word="banana";
    cout << "a = ";
    const char *pad = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            cout << pad << (i + 1);
            pad = ", ";
        }
    } 
    cout << "\n";
    return 0; }
```

and it's working perfectly , the only matter is i want it to print out the last order only .. for more clarity :
instead of printing out( a=2 , 4 , 6 ) in the last example i want it to print out (a=6)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already implemented as [the `find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) and [the `rfind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/) methods of `std::string`.

I recommend using one of these methods, but if you still want to implement yourself, you have to reverse the order to start from the end and not the begining, and I think you are looking for [the `break` statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_break_statement.htm) which stops the loop:

```
for (size_t i = word.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
  if (word[i] == 'a')
  {
    cout << pad << (i + 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Break works like this:

[image: break workflow]

Comment: `find_last_of` documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Comment: `rfind` also has a single character overload http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/

Comment: @user3432540: You can [read this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) for more on `break`, `continue` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the loop

```
for (size_t i = word.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   ...
```

If not for learning about loops, using the standard functions proposed in other answers are the right way to go.

Comment: This gives me a=6,4,2 while i want only a=6

Comment: You need to break when you find it obviously. I feel you are currently learning about loops so that is why I answered this as using the std::string is obviously the right answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::string::rfind` to get the index of the last occurrence of some character:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "banana";
    std::string::size_type pos = s.rfind( 'a' );
    if ( pos == std::string::npos ) {
        std::cout << "letter not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "letter found at position " << pos + 1 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to use the stl string find_Last_of function.  Below is a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string word="banana";
int pos = word.find_last_of("a");
cout << "Last occurrence of the letter a is at position " << pos+1 << " array position " << pos <<endl ;
return 0; }
```

Comment: No problem:) just remember to keep track of whether you need the lexical position (1 to 6 in banana; 1=b....6=a; language positions) or the array position (0 to 5 in banana; 0=b....5=a; C++ array positions), because if you address the array with the lexical positions then you will hend up missing one character at the lower end, and an out of bounds exception at the top end of the array (ie there is no position 6 in a range of 0-5)